# SQL - Workaround for Removing Last Element and Updating New one

Tags: php, sql

On my First SQL-Based Project.
I want a News pane on my website.
In that news pane. I want to show Latest 10 News of all time which I keep updating after every new change in website like a changelog.

What will be the workaround for SQL-PHP to Show only the Latest 10 News and How would I update the DataBase Table (Removing the Oldest, 10th Entry) and then Adding Latest(1st Entry) to the table + changing the IDs (1-10).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, You can Make a Table(e.g. News). With Column `ID` `content` `date`.

Simply Add the news and the do this.

`SELECT * FROM News ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10`

then,

Take this into PHP ARRAY and then simply work there.

Answer (score 0):

Rarely would you want to remove the old values from your database straight after adding a new entry, why not just order the database select results and limit the rows, far more flexible for future code changes.

```
SELECT * FROM News ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Assuming that you have timestamp for your news, you might want to order by this database value instead. As this would allow you to 'bump' up news articles later on, for example if you want an edited article to be considered new you would just have to update the timestamp, and not change the row ID to a higher value.

```
SELECT * FROM News ORDER BY unix_time_stamp DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Finally if you wanted to clean up your news entries I would do that on a cleanup function separately, probably on some kind of hourly or daily cronjob.

Comment: When There would be more than 10 row the IDs will start increasing. How am I suppose to show the Latest news(higher ID in table) to show as 1. News then Older as 2. and so on?